# HashMap key-value storage and retrieval

Tags: java, hashmap

In order to check and demonstrate getNextValue method if hashmap stores values if not present and retrieves from map if present, I added a main class below the method. Behavior is expected to be that value need to be taken from hashmap when 111 key is sent second time but each time value is put in hashmap. Am not sure which impacts - either Test is initialised in every loop or hashMap is initialized everytime due to which 111 wasn't available when 111 was sent second time?

Below is the code for reference.

```
    public List<String> getNextValue(Map<String,Object> requestparam){
        Map<String,List<String>> hashMap=new HashMap<>();
        String hashKey=requestparam.get("key");
        if(hashMap.containsKey(hashKey){
             return hashMap.get(hashKey

         } 
         else{
              List<String> value=new ArrayList<>();
              value.add("aa");
              hashMap.put(hashKey,value);
              return value;
          }

}

public static void main(String[] args){
     Test t=new Test();
     Map<String,Object> request=new HashMap<>();
     List<String> x=new ArrayList<>();
     x.add("111");
     x.add("111");
     x.add("222");
     for(String y:x){
        request.put("key",y)
        System.out.println(t.getNextValue(request));
}
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. What do you expect to happen and what is not working?

Comment: first time key->111 is sent , it is obvious that hashmap is empty so it puts into hashmap and it's fine.Next time i ain't sure why 111 is taken from hashmap and i see hashmap empty too in second run.

Comment: I expected hashmap to be {"111"=["aa"],"222"=["aa"]} in the end

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On each invocation of getNextValue, you create a new, **empty** HashMap.

```
public List<String> getNextValue(Map<String,Object> requestparam){
        Map<String,List<String>> hashMap=new HashMap<>();
```

This is why  `if(hashMap.containsKey(hashKey){` never matches.

Turn your hashMap local variable into a field of class Test:

```
public class Test {

 private final Map<String,List<String>> hashMap=new HashMap<>();

 public List<String> getNextValue(Map<String,Object> requestparam){ 
  // your code with line below removed:
  // Map<String,List<String>> hashMap=new HashMap<>(); 
  ...
 }
}
```

Comment: Silly me didn't realise that method is called eachtime. Thanks for your elaborate clarification!